# Read an audio file into a double sample array

Tags: android, audio, tarsosdsp

I'm writing an Android app that has to perform audio processing (more specifically, MFCC). I have decided to use the TarsosDSP library, but it does not provide a way to pass a sound file to it, as opposed to microphone input. This means that we currently have to write a class that implements a specific interface: basically, it's a wrapper around a buffer of `double`s.

Do you know of a way to get the samples as a `double` from a music file format that Android supports ? We've been scouring the net for a solution but we haven't found one that is generic enough.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while and found this:
https://0110.be/posts/Decode_MP3s_and_other_Audio_formats_the_easy_way_on_Android

You can still use the pipe in android. The code in the link allows you pass audio files directly into the decoder. It also contains the ffmpeg binaries required for the assets.

the link takes you through the steps. Good luck.

Comment: Can you please write down directly in your answer the relevant parts of the link that would help the person asking the question? Links are weak and are often not valid after a while.